# converting a string with 'nan' into numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I receive the string below from a file

```
data = 'data: [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -10.34, nan, 4.45533]'
```

and would like to convert this into a numpy array.
Is there a good way to do this in python?

I already tried this

```
x_values_list = np.fromstring(data[5:], dtype=float, sep=',')
```

But it just returns me [-1]

Comment: try `data[7:-1]` - you'll want to have only a comma-separated sequence of values, no extra characters like brackets etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion in the comments indicated that you need to slice to get rid of the brackets:

```
np.fromstring(data[7:-1], dtype=float, sep=',')
```

A more generic solution might be to use a regex to extract only the part between the brackets:

```
import re
import numpy as np

a = np.fromstring(re.search(r'(?<=\[)[^\[\]]+(?=\])', data).group(),
                  dtype=float, sep=',')
```

If you are not sure that there will be a match:

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=\[)[^\[\]]+(?=\])', data)
if m:
    a = np.fromstring(m.group(), dtype=float, sep=',')
else:
    a = np.array([])
```

output:

```
array([      nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,       nan,
       -10.34   ,       nan,   4.45533])
```

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't specify the desired output and / or restrictions in how to achieve it...

Assuming your goal is to get a `numpy.ndarray` similar to this

```
[  0.        0.        0.        0.        0.        0.      -10.34
   0.        4.45533]
```

then you can create a function like

```
import numpy as np

def string_to_numpy_array(data):
    data = data.replace('data: ', '')
    data = data.replace('[', '')
    data = data.replace(']', '')
    data = data.replace('nan', '0')
    data = data.split(',')
    data = [float(i) for i in data]
    data = np.array(data)
    print(data)
    print(type(data))
    return data
```

It basically

- removes `data:` , `[` and `]`
- replaces `nan` into `0`
- creates a float out of every item
- transforms it into the a numpy array
- prints the numpy array and the type for sanity

It's straightforward and whatever step you don't want you can easily take it out (for example, if you want `nan`, remove the line of the function where that gets replaced).

As you can see in the following image, if I test it

[image]

I get

[image]